# Clone is not getting all my branches from GitHub

Tags: git, github, octopress, github-pages

I followed the instructions [here](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/) to create a *GitHub Pages*-hosted blog using Octopress.

After the first deployment, two branches got created on GitHub: `source` and `master`.

Then I ran `git branch` and I noticed I only have one of the two branches locally. I ran `git pull`, expecting Git to download my other branch as well, but it instead merged the two branches.

I deleted my local repo and then did a git clone, expecting to get the two branches locally, but I Git only downloaded the `master` branch of my Weblog.

Any ideas what have I done wrong and how can I get my two branches locally?

---

### Update 1

Thanks for the answers. Just for sake of completeness, here's what I ended up doing:

```
git clone <github URL> -b source myblog
cd myblog
git clone <github URL> -b master _deploy
```

And then it was possible to continue with writing new posts, and deploying via `rake deploy`.

Comment: After cloning did you try `git checkout source` ? Also did you do `git branch -a` to show both local and remote tracking branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like nothing is wrong, actually. Your `source` branch should contain Octopress, so once you did `git checkout source`, you should be able to create your posts and then use corresponding `rake` tasks in order to generate static files, stage/commit/push them to the master branch on origin, which will make your posts accessible on Github Pages.

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between local branches and remote branches.  A git clone will fetch all information from the origin/remote.  And will checkout (create the local branch, which tracks its corresponding remote branch, and checks out the working files) the default branch of the repository.  Technically you should have `master`, `origin/master`, and `origin/source` branches in your cloned branch..but `git branch` only shows your local branch(es): `master`.  Run `git branch -a` to show all branches (local and remote).  Run a `git checkout source`, which will create a local branch based off of the remote branch.